# FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). How can I use Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I use this code to prepare the usage of the FaceBook API:

```
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

However, on document load I get the error of:

```
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

I don't understand this message. I've googled for this problem and found some forum threads, but unfortunately they were not helpful at all. I have decided to post a question here about this problem, as I am unable to resolve it, because I'm noob about Facebook API. Sorry if my question is too simple to anyone and thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: It's just as it says - you need to call `FB.init()`, which initializes your app information, before any other `FB` functions. Have you gone through the [SDK docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId: MS.FBAppID, // App ID from the App Dashboard
        //channelUrl: '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
        status: true, // check the login status upon init?
        cookie: true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

};

// Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
// Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
// contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
// Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
(function (d, debug) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document, /*debug*/false));
```

I had to use the Facebook AppID created for this application as AppID and I had to make sure that the domains are defined correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same Facebook Log

```
 ***FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().***
```

when document load. I find out that the `#xfbml=1` in the end of

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

make this error. After deleting `#xfbml=1`, it's fine!